# Start cmd openvpn-gui with arguments in QT

Tags: windows, qt, cmd, qprocess

I have a QT desktop aplication and now I want that when it starts it automatically calls openvpn to start too.

First try I've made it with a simple system() call, and it works, but it leaves cmd window in screen. I don't like it, but it works:

```
system("openvpn-gui --connect m2smart.ovpn")
```

But now I want to launch directly without needing the cmd window, and if I do it without arguments it works, this:

```
QProcess openvpn;
QString cmd("openvpn-gui.exe");
openvpn.startDetached(cmd);
```

Now, the only thing that I need is to indicate which config.ovpn to connect, like in the first example, I've searched how to do it and it seems to be like that:

```
QProcess openvpn;
QString cmd("openvpn-gui.exe");
QStringList args;

args << "--connect m2smart.ovpn";
openvpn.startDetached(cmd, args);
```

But it shows an openvpn window that says:

"Options error: unrecognized option or missing parameter(s): --connect m2smart.ovpn"

But if I open a cmd and put "openvpn-gui --connect m2smart.ovpn it works, independently of my working directory.

So... anyone can help me? I'm stucked with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried: `QProcess::startDetached("openvpn-gui --connect m2smart.ovpn")`?

Comment: @Mike working like a charm... thanks mate, so simple answer and didn't try it before.
But I'm still thinking why doesn't work what I've been testing... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [`QProcess::startDetached()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached) is a static method. There is no need to instantiate a `QProcess` object before calling it. You just need to do:

```
QProcess::startDetached("openvpn-gui.exe");
```

Now, We have two overloads for `QProcess::startDetached()`:

1. [`QProcess::startDetached(const QString& command)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1):

   There is no difference between this and using `system` function from the started program's point of view. So, on windows, if you had something like:

   ```
   QProcess::startDetached("openvpn-gui.exe --connect m2smart.ovpn");
   ```

   It would be the same as opening `cmd.exe` and typing `openvpn-gui.exe --connect m2smart.ovpn`.
2. [`QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments, const QString &workingDirectory = QString(), qint64 *pid = Q_NULLPTR)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached):

   From the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start):

   > On Windows, The arguments are **quoted** and joined into a command line that is compatible with the `CommandLineToArgvW()` Windows function.

   So, If you used something like this in your program:

   ```
   QString cmd("openvpn-gui.exe");
   QStringList args;
   args << "--connect m2smart.ovpn";
   QProcess::startDetached(cmd, args);
   ```

   This would be like opening `cmd.exe` and typing `openvpn-gui.exe "--connect m2smart.ovpn"`.

---

In the first case, the first argument passed to `openvpn-gui.exe` is `--connect` and the second argument is `m2smart.ovpn`.

In the second case, there is only one argument that is `--connect m2smart.ovpn`.

Comment: Perfect, this was the answer that I need. Thanks you mate!